# Odd,Even in ng-repeat Angular

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to detect odd or oven in ng-repeat . now i have a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/1242/)** that display some dots show/hide randomly , now i want to change background to not only red , for example odd = green and even = red .

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.lights = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    $scope.currentLight = 0;

    function light(index){
        if($scope.lights.length < index) {
            light(0);
        } else {
            $scope.currentLight = index;
         index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
            $timeout(function(){
                light(index);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    light(0);
}
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even`

from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd

```
<ol ng-init="names=['John', 'Mary', 'Cate', 'Suz']">
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
   <span ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
     {{name}}
   </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```